# How fast does this function converge to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, heat-equation

Consider the function given by $$f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto \int\limits_{-\delta}^{\delta}x^{2k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}dx,$$

where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\delta >0$. I know the function will converge to zero for $t\downarrow 0$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{t\downarrow 0}f(t)=0$. But I would like to know how fast the convergence is.

Is it for instance possible to show some estimate like: $f(t)\leq C\cdot t^{N(k)}$ for some number $N(k)$ or to show that $\lim\limits_{t\downarrow 0}t^{-\alpha}f(t)=0$, for some $\alpha >0 $?
If this is possible, which number $N(k)$ or $\alpha$ would be the best possible?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replaced $\delta$ by $\infty$, the integral would be $(4t)^k \Gamma(k+1/2)/\sqrt{\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

With $u = t/\sqrt t$:

$$
\int\limits_{-\delta}^{\delta}x^{2k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}
              e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}dx =
\int\limits_{-\delta/\sqrt t}^{\delta/\sqrt t}
t^k u^{2k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi }}
              e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}du \le
t^k \int\limits_{\Bbb R}
u^{2k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi }}
              e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}du 
$$
so $N(k) = k$ is okay.